# PHP: get_class_vars() vs. get_object_vars()

Tags: php

Regarding PHP, what are the differences between:

1. get_class_vars()
2. get_object_vars()

Comment: Go with PHP manual have much description

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`get_class_vars()` takes the class_name
`get_object_vars()` takes an $object variable

They both function similarly:

`get_class_vars()` will expose default public variables (or private/protected if called within the class)
`get_object_vars()` will expose the current public variables (or private/protected if called within the class object)

Neither will expose methods.

Comment: So one is for use with the definition (class), and the other is for use with an instance (object)?

Comment: This question is a little old, but I will make comment about something for new visitors. I believe that the `get_class_vars()` also get the **default** values of the attributes as mentioned in its doc. However,`get_object_vars()` will get the last values set to those attributes.In other words, the `get_class_vars()` [docs - example #1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) will ignore the new values set in the attributes while `get_object_vars()` will consider the "new" values.See [this example in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php#47075).

Comment: Another difference to note, `get_object_vars` will not return **uninitialized** properties, even if marked public.

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)
*"Uninitialized properties are considered inaccessible, and thus will not be included in the array."*

`get_class_vars` does not have that restriction.

If you could add that into the answer, @ohmusama, I think others might benefit.

Answer (score 17):

As you can see from the [`get_class_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) and [`get_object_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) manual pages, `get_class_vars` gets the *default* values of properties of a class, and `get_object_vars` gets the *current* values of properties of an object.

Furthermore, `get_class_vars` takes a string (ie. the name of a class), whereas `get_object_vars` takes an object.

```
class Example
{
  public $var = 123;
}

$e = new Example();
$e->var = 456;

var_dump(get_class_vars("Example"));
/*
array(1) {
  ["var"]=>
  int(123)
}
*/

var_dump(get_object_vars($e));
/*
array(1) {
  ["var"]=>
  int(456)
}
*/
```

Answer (score 5):

Theres one more thing:

`get_object_vars()` doesn't see static variables, but sees vars created during runtime!
`get_class_vars()` DOES SEE the static ones, but DOES NOT see new variables created during runtime, eg. in the constructor:

```
public function __construct() {$this->newval = "newval";}
```

Answer (score 1):

**As of PHP 5.5.9**

I have noticed that there's actually a slight difference between `get_class_vars` and `get_object_vars`.

Regarding to [**PHP Bug Report**](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66961), and I have tested it myself as well.

Both methods return the same result. **BUT, you can manipulate object properties by using `get_object_vars` and not with `get_class_vars`.**

Consider the following sample,

```
class Foo
{
  public $bar = null;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->bar = new DateTime(); // Now
    $this->far = &$this->bar;
  }
}
$foo = new Foo();
var_dump($foo);
$vars = get_object_vars($foo);
$vars['bar'] = new DateTime('2014-03-25');
var_dump($foo);
```

> In the sample above, you will notice that the second `var_dump` will
>   have `$foo->bar` modified.
>
> *Note: If you try to change the method from `get_object_vars` to
>   `get_class_vars`, you will also notice that `$foo->bar` will not be
>   modified.*

Answer (score 0):

get_class_vars() gives you even nonstatic variables, but their values are taken at the time of creating object, eg. init values.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this **very** unscientific (and probably quite error prone) performance test:

I used this class:

```
class foo {
    public $bar;
    public $baz = "abcd";
    public $qux = 123;
    public $quux;
    public $quuz = "abcd";
    public $corge = 1234;
}
```

and did test 1 (get_object_vars):

```
$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 1; $i >= 100000; $i++)  {
    $foo = new foo;
    $gov = get_object_vars($foo);
}
$end = microtime(ture);

echo $end - $start;
```

then test 2 (get_class_vars - replacing the inside of the for loop):

```
$gcv = get_class_vars("foo");
```

then test 3 (get_class_vars, and assuming you need to instantiate the object anyway - again replacing the for loop):

```
$foo = new foo();
$gcv = get_class_vars("foo");
```

I ran each one 5 times and these are the results I got:

test 1:
0.00014019012451172
0.00014519691467285
0.00014495849609375
0.00012087821960449
0.00012421607971191
AVG: 0.0001350879669

test 2:
0.00013995170593262
0.00012898445129395
0.00010204315185547
0.00013494491577148
0.00061392784118652
AVG: 0.0002239704132
(if we remove the outlier): 0.0001264810562

test 3:
0.00014710426330566
0.00012397766113281
0.00012612342834473
0.00011992454528809
0.00014090538024902
AVG: 0.0001316070557

In test two there was a weird outlier in round 5... not sure why... hiccup on my server.  If we remove that outlier, it looks like `get_class_vars()` is slightly more performant, regardless of whether you need to instantiate the class.

This test does not take into account any variable caching or php memory optimization that may be going on.  Of course in a real world application it's highly unlikely that you'll iterate over either of the functions 10k times.  So the functions' single and first execution performance is really more interesting, but much harder to test (accurately).